# Redirect HTTPS to HTTP except for specific URL

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, redirect, https

We'd like to redirect all HTTPS traffic to HTTP except for a specific URL which is /user/login

So far we've got:

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
RewriteRule ^user/login(.*)$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]
```

But it's causing a redirect loop, when it redirects back to HTTP

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this should do the trick:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Turn SSL on for /user/login
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/user/login
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

# Turn SSL off everything but /user/login
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/user/login
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

The above will do the following:

```
1. User types: https://yourdomain.com/user/login - no redirect
2. User types: http://yourdomain.com/user/login -> redirect to: https://yourdomain.com/user/login
3. User types: https://yourdomain.com/somerandomfile.php -> redirect to: http://yourdomain.com/somerandomfile.php
4. User types: http://yourdomain.com/somerandomfile.php - no redirect
```

Answer (score 5):

Something like this should work:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/user/login
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

But this doesn't make much sense for me. It would be better if you redirect only requests to /user/login via SSL and leave everything else as it is:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule /user/login(.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/user/login$1 [R,L]
```

Comment: Thanks. If we use HTTPS to serve the site then we lose the ability to cache pages with Varnish, so that's why I'd like to flip all HTTPS traffic back to HTTP except from the user login/account stuff, which we need to run over HTTPS

Comment: This still appears to send anyone visiting https://www.example.com/user/login to http://www.example.com/user/login ?

Answer (score -1):

You are looking for redirect when the URI does not match with /user/login/??
here is the answer.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7084048/apache-redirect-regexp-match-something-that-is-not-following-something/7084117#7084117

Comment: Nope, that's not what I'm looking for

Comment: talks about the same in your chosed as correct answer =) the key is the negation operator